# Carpet Calculator Program Final Edit

Tags: java

I asked a previous question of this same program. I would like more opinions before I submit this assignment since I edited the program after receiving feedback last time.

```
public class Room_Dimension 
{
    //Data fields 
    private double length;
    private double width;

    //Constructor 
    public Room_Dimension(double length, double width) 
    {
        super(); 
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    //Copy constructor 
    public Room_Dimension(Room_Dimension rd)
    {
        this.length = rd.getLength();
        this.width  = rd.getWidth();
    }

    //Accessors 
    public double getLength() 
    {
        return length;
    }

    public double getWidth() 
    {
        return width;
    }

    //Mutators  
    public void setLength(double length) 
    {
           this.length = length;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) 
    {
           this.width = width;
    }

    //Function to calculate the area 
    public double getArea() 
    {
        return length * width;
    }

    //Function to display information 
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Dimensions of room: (length = " + length + ", width = " + width + ")";
    }

}

public class Room_Carpet 
{
    //Data fields
    private Room_Dimension rd;
    private double carpetCost;

    //Constructor
    public Room_Carpet(Room_Dimension rd, double carpetCost) 
    {
        super(); 
        this.rd = rd;
        this.carpetCost = carpetCost;
    }

    //Copy constructor 
    public Room_Carpet(Room_Carpet rc)
    {
         this.rd             = rc.rd;
         this.carpetCost     = rc.getCarpetCost();
    }

    //Function to determine total cost of carpet that will fill area 
    public double getTotalCost() 
    {
        return carpetCost * rd.getArea();
    }

    //Function to get size 
    public Room_Dimension getSize()
    {
        return rd;
    }

    //Function to get carpet cost 
    public double getCarpetCost()
    {
        return carpetCost;
    }

    //Function to display information 
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "" + rd + ", Carpet cost per square feet = $" + carpetCost + ", " + "Total cost = $" + getTotalCost() + "";
    }

}

public class Carpet_Calculator 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Display information about program. 
        System.out.println("This program will display the carpet cost of a room.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the following information."); 

        // Get the length of the room.
        System.out.print("Enter the length of room: ");
        double length = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Get the width of the room.
        System.out.print("Enter the width of room: ");
        double width = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Get the cost of price per square feet of the desired carpeting.
        System.out.print("Enter the price per square feet for the desired carpeting: ");
        double carpetCost = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Close keyboard
        keyboard.close();

        // Create Room_Dimension and Room_Carpet objects.
        Room_Dimension dimension = new Room_Dimension(length, width);
        Room_Carpet roomCarpet = new Room_Carpet(dimension, carpetCost);

        // Print the object calling the toString
        System.out.println(roomCarpet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is near perfection, if you want to "get OCD" about it you can skip all the empty lines, comments on self-explanatory methods and fields and open code blocks on the same line, for example:

```
 public Room_Dimension(double length, double width)
{
    super(); 
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
```

and all the rest, could be written as:

```
 public Room_Dimension(double length, double width){
    super(); 
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
```

to save space, so that the class is visible within the screen with no need of scrolling. Additionally, search for *program layout* and *class interface* best practices, to get insight on the subject.

Comment: Thank you simplicis veritatis. The comments are so obvious but I leave them in there since my professor is very nitpicky about these things.

Comment: Its really easy to read and it looks great with or without the comments :)

Answer (score 4):

I would mostly agree with [*simplicis veritatis*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86897/31503) but would take it a fair amount further.

Yes, your code is neat, but, you are not following many of the standard Java common code conventions. I know that 'local rules' override common guidelines, but I feel I should point them all out anyway, in case you don't have an excuse.... ;-)

1. Java class names do not have an underscore in them. They use CamelCase. Your class `Room_Dimension` should be `RoomDimension`.
2. Java convention puts the open-brace at the end-of-line, not the start-of-next-line. Start-of-next-line is a C#, C, and other convention. So, code like:

   > ```
   > //Copy constructor 
   > public Room_Carpet(Room_Carpet rc)
   > {
   >      this.rd             = rc.rd;
   >      this.carpetCost     = rc.getCarpetCost();
   > }
   > ```

   should instead be:

   ```
   //Copy constructor 
   public Room_Carpet(Room_Carpet rc) {
        this.rd             = rc.rd;
        this.carpetCost     = rc.getCarpetCost();
   }
   ```
3. Your `Room_Dimension` should be an immutable class (you should not be able to change it). As a result, the `width` and `length` should be `final`, and there should be no 'setters' on it. How often do the dimensions of a room change? Your current class has an interesting spin-off: your `Room_Carpet` copy-constructor takes a copy of the reference to the Room_Dimension class... now, because it is a shallow copy, if someone changes the room dimension they change the details on **both** copies.
4. You should use `printf` when you can. Your lines of code like:

   > ```
   > return "Dimensions of room: (length = " + length + ", width = " + width + ")";
   > ```

   should instead be:

   ```
   return String.format("Dimensions of room: (length = %f, width = %f)", length, width);
   ```